# Return nullable date as return from user defined function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a user defined function as shown below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetDateTimeValue]
(
   @Stringval VARCHAR
)
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS
BEGIN
```

What I am trying to do is to extract the date from @Stringval. In case this string does not have a date, I would obviously like to return a blank value. How can I have the RETURN value in this case be a nullable date as there may not be a date all the time?

Comment: All SQL Server datatypes are nullable, just return null.

Comment: @DaleK - As such, I do not need to tweak the RETURNS as it will be a nullable DATETIME as created above, correct?

Comment: Correct........

Answer (score -1):

Due to how '' is treated by SQL as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 this doesn't work thanks to @Dale-k for pointing that out.
Since you want the field to be blank returning null is the correct answer.

Comment: Actually OP wants to return null, not a blank string - which will equate to the min datetime value.

Comment: @Dale-K I was responding to his statement in his post "In case this string does not have a date, I would obviously like to return a blank value." So I don't believe what I posted is wrong.

Comment: "How can I have the RETURN value in this case be a nullable date"

Comment: Try `select convert(datetime, '')` and see if it will return a blank datetime or not.

Comment: Hmm i see so it doesn't behave like normal languages where '' is treated as null but it placing it in ``1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`` instead. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your edited T-SQL is still doing stuff with blank strings?